# Where is the "Zero divide" done in kernel for Arm Cortex A-9

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel, divide-by-zero

I am looking into kernel source code (2.6.35 ) for Zero divide .

I inserted Zero divide in user space program and all threads stopped.

So I want to know Where is the "Zero divide" done in kernel for Arm Cortex A-9?

I am not able to find any trap for this ....

Thanks

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Err, you mean arithmetic exceptions? You tried to divide by zero in the kernel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the architecture. Given the following user space code on an **x86 system**:

```
main() {                                                                                                                                                                             
   int x = 42 / 0;                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

the compiler inserts a `idivl` command into the object code. When this command is executed with a divisor of 0, the CPU generates a division by zero trap (similar to an interrupt). This calls the `divide_error` trap handler inside the kernel, in case of x86 it is located in `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`:

```
ENTRY(divide_error)
        RING0_INT_FRAME
        pushl_cfi $0                    # no error code
        pushl_cfi $do_divide_error
        jmp error_code
        CFI_ENDPROC
END(divide_error)
```

The `error_code` target then takes care of all necessary actions to handle the error and finally returns from the trap.

---

On **ARM**, things are different: With a few exceptions, [ARM CPUs do not have a hardware division instruction](http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm) (e.g. Arm Cortex A-9 does not have one). Division needs to be implemented as a library function. For the kernel, this is implemented in `arch/arm/lib/lib1funcs.S` where you also find the division by zero handling. For user space applications, I suppose this is implemented as a library function in the libgcc library.

Comment: Thanks for this info .... I am using ARM Cortex-A9 Processor ....so where I Can similar code for ARM Cortex-A9 ?

Comment: Thanks Andreas For "Division by Zero in arm " explanation . I seen the file arch/arm/kernel/traps.c . In this file function asmlinkage void __div0(void) is there. If this function something to do with exception occurs in background at zero divide?