# Linux IDT hooking on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, interrupt

There are many documents and example code snippets for Linux x86/x64 IDT hooking.
But I can't find such documents for ARM.

I what I want to do is hook the ARM handler pointer of some interrupt/exception such as divide by zero, or svc 0.

It seems that ARM is somewhat different to Intel.

some advice would be nice
thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you have a [concept problem](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table).  See: [OSDev wiki IDT entry](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table), the IDT is specific to the x86.  For the ARM (non-Cortex-M, which I guess from the **Linux** tag) there is a single interrupt, which is responsible for reading the status from an interrupt controller and then branching to the appropriate routines.  See also: [Linux divide by zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526276/where-is-the-zero-divide-done-in-kernel-for-arm-cortex-a-9).  Can you please clarify what you want?

Comment: Some exception handers (e.g. data aborts) can be extended - see [`hook_fault_code`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=hook_fault_code), but whether that's appropriate here depends on what you're _actually_ trying to achieve.